# Obtain the average number of distinct values for each of the properties

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying with SPARQL querying to do this:

For each of the properties, obtain the average number of distinct values that they take for the instances (e.g., what is the average number of occupations for a Formula 1 Driver, what is the average number of teams that they have participated in, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a query like:

```
SELECT ?p (AVG(?ct) AS ?avg)
WHERE {
   SELECT ?s ?p (COUNT(DISTINCT ?o) AS ?ct) 
   WHERE {
      ?s ?p ?o .
      #more restrictions...
          }
   GROUP BY ?s ?p }
GROUP BY ?p
```

Notice that this approach ignores instances where the count is 0, i.e. a F1 driver with no profession.

Also, the query is likely to time out unless you add some more restrictions to reduce the size of the matched data.